# How could I use "ROS" commands in a bash file?

Tags: ros, script, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ! First, i'm sorry for my english , i don't use translator and i'm not really good at.

Let me explain my problem :
I want to use "PuTTY" via Windows' terminal (to connect to linux) with the arguments "-m" and a file .txt
This file will be read by PuTTY and execute line by line the commands.
But there's a problem , every linux' commands works, but "catkin_make" or "rosrun" it wrote :

bash: line 2: catkin_make: command not found

per exemple

However , i can use it manually via PuTTY

How can I use ROS commands in a bash file ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292033/how-could-i-use-%22ros%22-commands-in-a-bash-file-?/) by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an environment setup issue (ie: the environment is not correctly setup). Passing absolute paths to commands will work around some problems, but not all (ie: `rospkg` not being able to find ROS packages and others).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
@gvdhoorn  so what do you recommand me ?
It's my mate who had installed all the things , and I need to wait him to make some test (he's absent atm)
I don't know which commands we need ( catkin_make , rosrun , but don't know the others )
I'll be back with more informations
Thanks for your answer

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:
You have a few options, but I don't know how Putty treats each of the lines in your `-m file.txt`: if they are all executed in individual SSH sessions, then you'll need to `source` the correct `setup.bash` *each time* before you run a new command.

If it's all a single session, `source` once.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
Well , isn't enough if we sourced it in the .bashrc ?
I will try to get some infos about the `-m` so ! :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:\

> Well , isn't enough if we sourced it in the .bashrc ?

It can be, but regular SSH logins do not source `$HOME/.bashrc`. That is not a ROS problem btw, just how SSH/bash work.

If you solve/work-around that, your initial approach might work.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
Thanks for your answers !
I'll make some tests and i'll come back

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
hey , so with the source : `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make`

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.init_workspace import init_workspace
ImportError: No module named catkin.init_workspace
```

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
I used :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd catkin_ws
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make 2>> erreurs.log
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:
I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do exactly.

In a nutshell, I believe you need to:

1. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
2. run your commands

you cannot `source` `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
Like that catkin_make works

but as you said earlier , rosrun :

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package hello_world_demo not found
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:
Well if you have pkgs in a workspace then of course you should `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` instead.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
i did :

```
#!/bin/bash
        cd Ben_catkin_ws
        source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash 2> erreurs.log
        source /devel/setup.bash
        rosrun hello_world_demo youBot_HelloWorldDemo 2>> erreurs.log
```

Didn't work, even if i delete the source hydro

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-25**:
(ah and yes , i use kinetic for test , and hydro on the robot)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:
This doesn't match:

```
cd Ben_catkin_ws
...
source /devel/setup.bash
```

Either your `devel` space is in the root (`/`) of the drive, or it's in `Ben_catkin_ws`. It cannot be both.

Also: I'd advise you to use absolute paths with `source`.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-28**:
Should i use ben_catkin_ws devel ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-28**:
If that is the workspace containing your packages, then that would make sense, yes.

Please take note of the capitalisation though. You now write `ben_catkin_ws`, but in your other comments it's `Ben_catkin_ws`. Case matters.

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-28**:
I'll try when i got the robot back :)

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-31**:
Well , awesome it worked !

Thanks a lot @gvdhoorn , i understand my mistake here.

```
 /devel/setup.bash
```

is

```
/home/path/to/devel/setup.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you are facing such issue. try to give the complete path of the command. `catkin_make` and `rosrun`.

`catkin_make` command is useful only in the catkin_workspace. Navigate to the workspace and then run the command by complete path `/opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make` for catkin_make. `/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosrun <package _name> <executable>` for rosrun.

Note: Change the indigo with the installed distro.

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fjara](https://answers.ros.org/users/35407/fjara/) on 2018-05-24**:
Thanks for the quick answer, i'll try it as fast as i can !